# Scaling of the hazard function and relationship with variance

Tags: survival, moments, hazard

Say I have some random variable with known mean $\mu$, known variance $\sigma^2$ and known hazard function $\lambda(t)$. Is there a closed form expression for the variance of the random variable with hazard function $c\lambda(t)$ where $c>0$ is some constant? I wonder whether this might have been explored in relation to proportional hazards models...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *complementary* CDF of the random variable $X$ with hazard rate $\lambda(t)$ is
$$1- F_X(x) = \exp\left(-\int_0^x \lambda(t) \,\mathrm dt\right).$$
The *complementary* CDF of the random variable $Y$ with hazard rate $c\lambda(t)$ is
\begin{align}
1-F_y(x) &= \exp\left(-\int_0^x c\lambda(t) \,\mathrm dt\right)\\
&= \left[\exp\left(-\int_0^x \lambda(t) \,\mathrm dt\right)\right]^c\\
&= \big[1- F_X(x)\big]^c.\end{align}
Thus,
$$f_Y(x) = -\left.\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right[1- F_Y(x)
\right] = c\big[1- F_X(x)\big]^{c-1}f_X(x)$$
showing that it is not a simple relation such that knowing the mean and variance of $X$ allows us to easily deduce that the mean and variance of $Y$ are; one needs to put in more work and perhaps consider specific examples of hazard rates to find the answer. Of course, a simple example of where very little effort is needed is the case of *constant* hazard rates when both $X$ and $Y$ are exponential random variables.

Comment: If I squint at your last equation, and assume $c$ is an integer, it looks like the PDF of the minimum of $c$ IID $X$s. Can that be exploited? i) gives a fast way to MC a solution, ii) some bounds could be derived / provided.

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon Neat observation! I've realised that I don't actually need this for my application, so it's demoted to a bit of a curiosity, but there may be some results on the variance of order statistics that are applicable?